# how to add an json object as an element to another json

Tags: json, bash, shell

i create a json object by a script with jq.

```
jq -n --arg date "$DATE" --arg script "$SCRIPT" --arg log_level "$LOG_LEVEL" --arg ppid "$PPID" --arg message "$MESSAGE" '{"t":$date, "service":$script, "level":$log_level, "pid":$ppid, "message":$message}'
```

The Variable log_level and message are provided by another script and in message there can be stored a plain string or a json string.

Example Json String:

```
{"text":"value", "text2":"value2"}
```

Output if a a plain string is provided:

```
{
  "t": "2017-10-12 16:52:26",
  "service": "import.sh",
  "level": "INFO",
  "pid": "23425",
  "message": "START"
}
```

Output if a json object is provided:

```
{
    "t": "2017-10-12 17:01:16",
    "service": "import.sh",
    "level": "INFO",
    "pid": "13069",
    "message": "{\"text\":\"value\", \"text2\":\"value2\"}"
}
```

What i expected if i provide the json object:

```
{
    "t": "2017-10-12 17:01:16",
    "service": "cis_import.sh",
    "level": "INFO",
    "pid": "13069",
    "message": {
        "text": "value",
        "text2": "value2"
    }
}
```

Am i right that jq add the `\` for each `"` because it gets added to the json object like it would be a simple string?

How can i get my expected json?

Comment: Have you tried using the `--argjson` of `jq` ?

Comment: Note that you have to know if `message` contains a string or a JSON object before you can decide whether you need `--arg` or `--argjson`. It will be simpler if you can ensure that whatever provides `message` always returns a proper JSON value (meaning it might return `"START"` instead of `START`). Then you can use `--argjson` unconditionally.

Comment: Is there a way to validate a shell variable with jq? I just found a way to validate if the content of a file is a json. 
`jq . /path/to/file.json`
With this i do `--arg v "$variable` if its a simple string or i do `--slurpfile v /path/to/file.json`
If possible i would like to stay in the shell and not write a file and remove it later.

Comment: i added `"` to the variable, so it looks like this `"START"`and used  `--argjson v $variable`.
the output looks like this now:
`{"t":"2017-10-13 09:52:02","service":"import.sh","level":"INFO","pid":"4566","message":["START"]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally. Thanks for the hints [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepn)
and [blusky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4380515/blusky)

To validate if `$MESSAGE`is a json i use `jq -n $MESSAGE` see [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) instead of `jq . /path/to/file.json`

To use the mentioned `--argjson` i will add `"` around `$MESSAGE`if the $MESSAGE is a plain string `MESSAGE="\"$MESSAGE\""`. I do this with DATE, SCRIPT, LOG_LEVEL, PPID too.

Command to create the json object looks like this:

`jq -cn --argjson date "$DATE" --argjson script "$SCRIPT" --argjson log_level "$LOG_LEVEL" --argjson  ppid "$PPID" --argjson message "$MESSAGE" '{"t":$date, "service":$script, "level":$log_level, "pid":$ppid, "message":$message}'`